# Duplicated Break Points in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio

I am having a problem which I can't quite understand.

I put a breakpoint in one page, and when I debug, another break points appear from another .cpp.

Does anyone know what could be the source of the problem here?

Please help.

thanks

Comment: 17 questions and only 1 accepted. You have to work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 possible causes, but it's not really a problem:

- The compiler inlines function, so when you set a breakpoint in that function, it automatically sets breakpoints to wherever it is encountered.
- The optimizer squeezed more methods in the same location, so all could be marked.

Will add more if I can think of any.

Comment: thanks. But I am pretty sure it is not inline function. (I rechecked it after you mentioned it.) So that leaves out the optimizer posibility. I am not too sure about this either because I checked the project debug option but it says "No optimization /ob" something like this.

Comment: @user1047092 well that rules out the second option. Can you post some code? Did you do a full rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did. I rebuilded manytimes. But those code I wish I can post right now, but I cannot because I don't have it. (it is work related sorry). I read somewhere that VS automatically puts another break points if the function is a overriding function?(Sort of Child break?)

Comment: @user1047092 can you replicate this behavior on a smaller example? Also, how do you know the functions aren't inlined?

Comment: I have seen it but let's say it is inline function, How would you fix this problem?

Comment: @user1047092 what do you mean you have seen it? It doesn't have to be declared `inline` to be inlined if that's what you mean. And if it is, it's not a problem, it's expected. If you don't like it, you need to make it not inline.